Zapier using data from a initial api call in the second
I am struggling with how Zapier works I do not fully understand how to make 2 calls with data from the fist call.
I am trying to use the response from the first one but it return a promise and I cannot figure out how to use await and async without it being invalid.
const options = {
  url: `https://url.sample/${bundle.authData.tenant}/api//${bundle.inputData.catalogs}/items?skip=0&limit=1`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': bundle.authData.token
  },
  params: {

  },
  removeMissingValuesFrom: {
    'body': false,
    'params': false
  },
}

let data = z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    const results = response.json;

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results;
  });
  
const options2 = {
  url: `https://url.sample/${bundle.authData.tenant}/api/${bundle.inputData.catalogs}/items/${data[0].id}`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': bundle.authData.token
  },
  params: {

  },
  removeMissingValuesFrom: {
    'body': false,
    'params': false
  },
}

let data2 = z.request(options2)
  .then((response) => {
    const results = response.json;

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results;
  });
  
let final_result = [];
    for (let i of data2.apps) {
        data.push({"eventName": "catalog.app.completed", "catalog": bundle.inputData.catalogs, "record": data.ID, "app": i.name });
    }

return final_result;

